# Is it possible to insert elements in an array sortedly (in ascendent order)? Or is it better to sort after all the elements are already in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, insert, buffer

For example, being the input:

`4 2 120 -2 3`

Is it better (**complexity time**) to insert every element sortedly?

```
int array[n];
int val;
int pl = 0;

pl++;
int aux = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pl; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > val)
    {
        aux++;
        for (int j = pl; j >= i; j--)
        {
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            array[i] = val;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (aux == 0)
        array[pl - 1] = val;
}

print_array();
```

**Output:**
`-2 2 3 4 120`

Or is it better to just fill the array in the given input order and then just sort the array?

```
int array[n];
int val;

for (int i = 0; i < n and cin >> val; ++i)
   array[i] = val;
 
print_array();

quicksort(array);

print_array();
```

**Output:**

```
4 2 120 -2 3 //array before quicksort
-2 2 3 4 120 //array after quicksort
```

Comment: You should use a binary search to insert the sorted element, not a linear search.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Doesn't generally help. To insert in order, you have to touch (on average) half the already-inserted elements anyway.

Comment: Have you considered just storing your data in a std::set or std::multiset instead? Search, insertion, and removal operations have logarithmic complexity, which may be good enough for what you're trying to accomplish. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset

Answer (score 2):

Generally better to insert as received, then sort.

If you insert each item in order, each insertion is O(N), and you do it N times, so you end up with O(N<sup>2</sup>) overall complexity.

If you insert them in the order received, then use a QuickSort (or similar, such as IntroSort, which is how `std::sort` is often implemented) you end up with O(N log N) instead.

Comment: Hmm why each insertion is O(N)?

Comment: @Slava: Because you need to move (on average) half of the already-inserted elements to make a space for the new one.